# 2D array pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

Say I have an int array: `int arr[5][5]` and assume C language memory management.

I want to access a particular element of the array using only pointer arithmetic and dereferencing.

Suppose I wanted to access the element in:  `arr[i][j]`

I tried printing a few things at first to understand how the addresses worked. 
I printed the address of `arr`, `arr+1`, and `arr+2`, and `arr+5`.

These were the results:

```
0x7fff58475b80
0x7fff58475b94
0x7fff58475ba8
0x7fff58475be4
```

I'm wondering why the difference between each of address is 14(in Hexadecimal) or 20 (in decimal).

Also, when you create a 2-D array on the stack, is a pointer to an array of pointers to memory blocks created? This is how I assume we allocate space for the array:

1. Allocate a pointer `arr` on stack.
2. The `arr` pointer holds the address to the starting location of an array of pointers.
3. That array of pointers contains the starting location of a row in the 2-D array.

Is this correct?

EDIT: Also, assume you wanted to access arr[i][j] through pointer arithmetic. How would this be done? If the array is allocated dynamically, I think you can do *( * (arr+i)+j). I'm not sure how you do this for static allocations? My guess is *(arr + ((row_size * (i))+j)). Is this correct?

Comment: `arr` is an array of 5 elements, of type `int[5]` each. `sizeof(int[5]) == 20`

Comment: `is a pointer to an array of pointers to memory blocks created?` No. A flat array of "memory blocks" is created, each "block" in turn an array. Perhaps this will make it clearer: `int arr[5][5]` is the same as `typedef int Block[5]; Block arr[5];`

Comment: There are no pointers involved in `int arr[5][5];`. Arrays and pointers are different.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm wondering why the difference between each of address is 14(in Hexadecimal) or 20 (in decimal).

Perhaps because on your system the size of `int` is `4` and there are `5` ints in the inner array.

To get the idea about layout, try the following code:

```
int a[5][5];
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        a[i][j] = ++k;
int* p = &a[0][0];
for (int n = 0; n < 25; n++, p++)
    printf("%d ", *p);
```

Output is

```
1 2 3 4 ... 25
```

---

There is a note in the `C++` standard (in **8.3.4 Arrays [dcl.arrays]**):

> [ Note: It follows from all this that arrays in C++ are stored row-wise (last subscript varies fastest) and that
>   the first subscript in the declaration helps determine the amount of storage consumed by an array but plays
>   no other part in subscript calculations. —end note ]

Answer (score 1):

The linear address of location [i,j] in a 2d matrix is calculated by:

```
linear_position = i * (capacity of column 0) + j;
```

The address is calculated from the linear position by using the size of array type and using the starting address of the array:

```
cell_address = &array[0][0] + linear_position * sizeof(array[0][0]);
```

Plugging in your values into the above equations should give you an indication of the differences in addresses.

Comment: `capacity of column` Did you mean capacity of row?

Answer (score 1):

(1)The memory address of all 5*5 elements of arr[5][5] is  &arr[0][0], &arr[0][1] ... & arr[0][4], &arr[1][0], ... &arr[1][4], ... &arr[4][4]. They are all arranged in sequence with the difference of sizeof (int). In your os, sizeof (int) = 4.

(2) From the perspective of address,
arr+1 = &arr[1][0], arr+2 = &arr[2][0]. They are just different representation. The former is pointer form, the later is array form.

Answer (score 1):

Array is a collection of similar data elements stored in contiguous memory location.

```
int arr[5][5];
```

In this declaration, it will allocate contiguous memory location for all elements. say starting memory location is 1000.

```
array  starting   array elements
       address
arr[0]--> 1000 --> arr[0][0] arr[0][1] ... arr[0][4]
arr[1]--> 1020 --> arr[1][0] arr[1][1] ... arr[1][4]
arr[2]--> 1040 --> arr[2][0] arr[2][1] ... arr[2][4]
arr[3]--> 1060 --> arr[3][0] arr[3][1] ... arr[3][4]
arr[4]--> 1080 --> arr[4][0] arr[4][1] ... arr[4][4]
```

---

```
I'm wondering why the difference between each of address is 14(in Hexadecimal) or 20 (in decimal).
```

Each array has 5 integer, `sizeof(int)` is 4. So for 5 integers it will allocate 20 bytes of memory. Due to this only you are getting the difference between each array address is 20 bytes(in decimal. In hexadecimal it is 14)

---

```
1. Allocate a pointer `arr` on stack.
```

-No. Allocate a pointer to pointer to a integer (`arr`) on stack. That is `int **arr;`

```
2. The arr pointer holds the address to the starting location of an array of pointers.
3. That array of pointers contains the starting location of a row in the 2-D array.
```

Now it is correct! But This is dynamic memory allocation not static!